# Spring roo reverse engineering: schema not recognized

Tags: spring, reverse-engineering, h2, spring-roo

I want to reverse engineer a h2 database:

[image]

roo suggests the two available schemas INFORMATION_SCHEMA and PUBLIC but using them results in an error "Schema(s) 'PUBLIC' do not exist or does not have any tables..."

[image]

Roo version: 1.3.2

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:
Output of the log.roo:

```
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev 8387857] log opened at 2016-05-26 09:04:31
project --topLevelPackage de.max.test
persistence setup --database H2_IN_MEMORY --provider HIBERNATE 
// [failed] database introspect --schema unable-to-obtain-connection 
osgi start --url  file:///C:/Users/max/Downloads/h2/h2-1.4.191.jar
database introspect --schema PUBLIC 
database introspect --schema INFORMATION_SCHEMA 
database introspect --schema no-schema-required
database reverse engineer --schema PUBLIC
```

database.properties:

```
#Updated at Thu May 26 10:25:51 CEST 2016
#Thu May 26 10:25:51 CEST 2016
database.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
database.url=jdbc\:h2\:mem\:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY\=-1
database.username=sa
database.password=
```

The establishing of a connection seems to work since roo detects the two schems INFORMATION_SCHEMA and PUBLIC.

Comment: Could you update your answer to provide a `log.roo` file with the executed commands and  all the necessary steps and configurations to be able to reproduce your issue? Regards,

Comment: Seems like Spring Roo shell is not establishing connection to your DB. Try to create a new schema using `CREATE SCHEMA` statement on your H2 shell. Then, add new table to that schema using "CREATE TABLE SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME(testname varchar(10))". Now, if you use `database introspect` roo command is showing you the new created schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jcgarcia.
The connection was indeed not established. I changed the database.url to

`database.url=jdbc:h2:~/test`

That worked but roo could definitely be improved by stating that a connection could not be established.

Comment: Feel free to create an improvement on [Spring Roo JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO) issue tracker. Regards.